# Mootools element injection

Tags: mootools, element, code-injection

im sorry if this has already been covered, i have had a look but didn't come acrross a question - answer ( I have found so many answers to my question on here in the past - keep up the good work guys + gals )

Im learning Mootools element injection, I have not been using this for long and I am finding it is opening my eyes to all sorts of usages. My question is how do I construct a new image element that is linked to a url? for example how do I inject;

```
<a href="[url]"><img src="[path]" /></a>
```

I can do this as 2 seperate elements  &  but struggling to combine them as one element.  thank you for reading my question and for any advice given.

Mark

Comment: thanks for your responses, ive been experimenting and have come up with the following solution for my needs

    photos.each(function(photo){
        var el = new Element('div.image'),
        image = new Element('img', {
            'src': photo.src 
        }).inject(el),
        defaultLink = new Element( 'a', {
            'class': 'makeImageDefault', 'name': photo.id
        }).inject(image, 'after'),
        defaultImageIcon = new Element( 'img', { 
            'src': photo.defaultIcon 
        }).inject(defaultLink, 'inside' )
        el.inject($('photoGrid'));
    });

Comment: Now im facing a 2nd issue once injection has completed. The link thats injected class="makeImageDefault" is connected to $$('a.makeImageDefault').addEvent() which works to initiate the new injection does not work after injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Elements.from`, it's fast, perfectly valid, and simple.

```
var collection = '<a href="{href}"><img src="{src}" /></a>';
Elements.from(collection.substitute({
    href: 'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
    src: 'http://www.placekitten.com/300/300'
})).inject(document.body);
```

An obvious disadvantage is that you have no references to the nodes created, only to the collection of elements.

Comment: +1, esp for the `.substitute` which is so underused! Elements.from is a reliance on mootools-more http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Elements.From though.

Comment: +1, much better answer than mine. I'm still learning MooTools so this is helpful `:)`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, I love `.subsitutute`, I kind of wish we could use paths with it, ie. `'<a href="{link/url}">'.substitute({link: {url: '/'}})`

Comment: hrm so really `{link.url}` should resolve to your object? interesting. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/aRv7A/ at a first read, testing with `gay.bar.name` (3 levels only but it will be infinite). I find that helpful to have, though i think we could probably work on performance (better loop etc).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`grab`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agrab) or [`inject`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3ainject) on two new elements (an `img` and `a`) to nest them:

```
var anchor = new Element("a", {
    href: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
});

var img = new Element("img", {
    src: "http://www.placekitten.com/300/300"
});

// inject the img into the anchor
img.inject(anchor);

// Append the anchor into the body:
document.body.grab(anchor);
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/300/300">
</a>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tNamz/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your responses, ive been experimenting and have come up with the following solution for my needs

```
photos.each(function(photo){
    var el = new Element('div.image'),
    image = new Element('img', {
        'src': photo.src 
    }).inject(el),
    defaultLink = new Element( 'a', {
        'class': 'makeImageDefault', 'name': photo.id
    }).inject(image, 'after'),
    defaultImageIcon = new Element( 'img', { 
        'src': photo.defaultIcon 
    }).inject(defaultLink, 'inside' )
    el.inject($('photoGrid'));
});
```

Comment: Now im facing a 2nd issue once injection has completed. The link thats injected class="makeImageDefault" is connected to $$('a.makeImageDefault').addEvent() which works to initiate the new injection does not work after injection

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from you success.  Cheers~